# Captch image created using CaptchImageResource is not displayed immediately with rest of web page contents, but after about 5 seconds delay

Tags: wicket

I am working with Apache NetBeans IDE 11.3, Wicket 9.0.0, JDK 11, Payara server, Java EE 8 web.

Captcha image on web page is not displayed immediately along with rest of page contents, but after about 5 seconds delay. Clicking of Refresh link, shows new captcha image, again after about 5 seconds delay.

Following source shows simple code I have written to use CaptchaImageResource. I want to test CaptchaImageResource, with my challenge text, not randomly generated text.

```
    Image captchaImage = new NonCachingImage("captchaImage", new CaptchaImageResource() {
        @Override
        protected byte[] render() {
            getChallengeIdModel().setObject("MyText1010");
            super.setLastModifiedTime(Instant.now());
            return super.render();
        }
    });
    captchaImage.setOutputMarkupId(true);
    captchaImage.setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true);
    add(captchaImage);
    Image refreshImage = new Image("refreshImage",
        new PackageResourceReference(CaptchaPage.class, "refresh.png"));
    AjaxLink refreshLink = new AjaxLink("refreshLink") {
            @Override
            public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget art) {
                captchaImage.setImageResource(new CaptchaImageResource() {
                    @Override
                    protected byte[] render() {
                        getChallengeIdModel().setObject("SomeText1234");
                        super.setLastModifiedTime(Instant.now());
                        return super.render();
                    }}
                );
                art.add(captchaImage);
            }            
    };
    add(refreshLink);
```

Has anyone faced this problem?

Thanks

Rajani

Comment: Hi, it might be some kind of bottleneck problem. Have you debugged your code to see if there's any particular point where it slows down? 
PS: what's the purpose of 'Image refreshImage'? It seems it's not used at all.

Comment: Yes I did try debugging. after 'return super.render()', it takes about 5 seconds. Sorry I missed the last line of the code, which was 'refreshLink.add(refreshImage)'. Clicking on this link shows second captcha, which again is delayed by about 5 seconds, after same 'return super.render'. The image shown by refreshImage (referring to 'refresh.png') displays right away. but not the captcha images.